# Spatial regression results using spreg are different than GeoDa with same parameters

Tags: python

I performed the Spatial Lag Model in GeoDa and in python via the pysal spreg package with the same parameters but I am getting very different spatial lag values between the two outputs. The spatial weights matrix is a 1st order queen contiguity. I generated one in GeoDa, and I also generated a weights matrix in python using

```
wq = weights.contiguity.Queen.from_dataframe(df)
```

as well as this

```
df_w = weights.contiguity.Queen.from_dataframe(df, geom_col='geometry', idVariable='ZCTA5CE10')
```

When I manually inspect the weight matrixes they contain the same information. The wq matrix uses the dataframe index as the ID, and the df_w uses the ZIP code value as the ID. The same information is there, although the order of items is different. The GeoDa weights matrix also has the same info, different order.

If I run a spatial lag model in python using the wq matrix, the spatial lag value is 0.046. If i run it with the df_w matrix the lag value is 0.005. And in GeoDa the lag value is 0.35. These are orders of magnitude in difference. The AIC and r2 values are also different.

Here is the python code:

```
ML_Lag2 = spreg.ML_Lag(
# Dependent variable
df[["EROOD_5yrA"]].values,
# Independent variables
df[var_names].values,
# Spatial weights matrix
w=wq,
#calculation method
method='full',
# Dependent variable name
name_y="EROOD_5yrA",
# Independent variables names
name_x=var_names,
)
print(ML_Lag2.summary)
```

The reason I want to ensure I can run a spatial lag  model reliably in python is so I can use the regimes function which GeoDa doesn't include. I was about to write up results of my spatial lag regime models when I realized the spatial lag was so different.

I thought a potentially viable way to troubleshoot would be to read in the GeoDa .gal weights matrix in python, but I couldn't get the .gal file to be read in as a weight object.

Any advice? Thanks in advance.